# Qual o nome para a figura de linguagem na expressão "Este local fica a 5 minutos de distância"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, figuras-de-linguagem

Recentemente presenciei um diálogo onde um dos falantes comentou com o outro:

> Estou me mudando para um local próximo daqui, apenas 5 minutos de distância.

O sentido de "5 minutos de distância" é evidente (tão perto que em 5 minutos de deslocamento se chega lá), mas fiquei pensando nesta expressão, onde há uma mistura de unidades de medida (tempo com distância propriamente dita).

Me lembrei da figura de linguagem chamada [sinestesia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestesia), onde há um cruzamento de sentidos humanos (como em [*As Cidades e as Serras* de Eça De Queirós](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000081.pdf), “E um doce vento, que se erguera, punha nas folhas alagadas e luzidias um frémito alegre e doce.”).

Pode-se chamar de sinestesia a figura de linguagem no caso citado? Ou existe uma figura mais adequada?

Comment: @Jacinto, como descobriste o nome da obra de Eça de Queirós? Conhecimento prévio? Ou conheces alguma ferramenta que permite procurar uma obra a partir de um trecho conhecido?

Comment: Procurei a frase no Google Books. Mas havia um erro: a wikipedia tem *lustrosas*, mas é *luzidias*. Quando procurei «punha nas folhas alagadas e lustrosas um frémito alegre e doce», o Google Books não encontra e faz uma sugestão deveras curiosa. Depois procurei «E um doce vento, que se erguera», e encontrei logo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metalepse, ao citar o tempo que percorrer a distância tomará (a consequência) no lugar da distância em si (a causa).

"Metalepse. [...] Figura em que se toma o antecedente pelo consequente, e vice versa: Eles viveram (por eles estão mortos); Surgiram as flores (por é primavera)." Buarque de Holanda (1965). Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa. 1a edição, 14a impressão.

Comment: Marcelo, tens alguma fonte para citar a respeito?

Comment: @gmauch Sim, claro.
"Metalepse. [...] Figura em que se toma o antecedente pelo consequente, e vice versa: _Eles viveram_ (por _eles estão mortos_); _Surgiram as flores_ (por _é primavera_)."
Buarque de Holanda (1965). Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa. 1a edição, 14a impressão.